# Text in activation rectangle in PUML sequence diagrams

Tags: plantuml

Is it possible to add text in the activation rectangle in `PlantUML`?
Something like this:

[image]

The code for the above diagram:

```
@startuml
activate Alice
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response

Alice -> Bob: Another authentication Request
Alice <-- Bob: another authentication Response
deactivate Alice
@enduml
```

Comment: Do you want to have a text with each arrow in the bar or just a text in the bar? To the best of my knowledge neither is possible.

Comment: @albert just in the rectangle area.

Comment: Adding text over the activation bar is not really an UML feature. Why don't you use notes? You can choose the note location.